# Generate models diagram loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I've made the relations between models through the JSON object and I want  to generate the models diagram to see if they were made ok. Does anybody knows how can I do that? (I wasn't able to find any useful information about that)

Comment: There is no tools for viewing data model in loopback. You can create your schema in database and view data model in database management tools

Comment: How can i test if the relations between models are made correctly ? I looked up my database and there were no relations between tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL, you can generate a database diagram using the MySQL Workbench: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: The problem is that the tables are generated with  MyISAM type, so they can't have Foreign key. This is way I want to generate from loopback.